# Symfony 2: How to execute sql queries in a service

Tags: php, symfony

Last week I started working with Symfony 2 and I am bit confused about how to use models and how to create own specific functions.

I have created a service **Testing** in the services.yml file:

```
services:
testing:
class: AppBundle\Service\MyService
 arguments: [ @doctrine.orm.entity_manager ]
```

This is the class MyService

```
class myService
{

/**
 * @InjectParams({
 *    "em" = @Inject("doctrine.orm.entity_manager")
 * })
 */


  public function __construct(EntityManager $em)
  {
  $this->em = $em;
  }


  function getQuery($id){
   $sql = "SELECT firstname FROM players WHERE id = $id";

    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $stmt = $em->getConnection()->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->execute();
    $players = $stmt->fetchAll();
}
```

I would like to execute a query in the service and load the function getQuery() in the controllor like this:

```
$locationService = $this->container->get('testing');
$ownFunction = $locationService->getQuery($id);
```

When I execute the script above I get an error.

Comment: what error do you get?

Comment: You are already injecting `EntityManager` in your service definition. There is not need to use `Inject` annotation. You can directly access `$this->em`

Comment: Seems pretty clear that your annotation is useless. Drop it and try again

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `getQuery` method is wrong. Since you have `EntityManager` injected into constructor you should use it (you don't have `getDoctrine` method available in your service``)

```
public function getQuery($id){
    $sql = "SELECT firstname FROM players WHERE id = :id";

    $stmt = $this->em->getConnection()->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->bindValue(':id', $id); //you should do this to be sql-injection safe
    $stmt->execute();

    return $stmt->fetchAll(); //you didn't return anything in your function


}
```

**EDIT**: you also miss `use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager;` at the top of your class

Comment: Hi, I tried to rewrite the script according to your suggestions, but I get always the same errorCatchable Fatal Error: Argument 1 passed to AppBundle\Service\Testing::__construct() must be an instance of AppBundle\Service\EntityManager, instance of Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager given, called in /WWW/lab.blueeye.ch/www/app/cache/dev/appDevDebugProjectContainer.php on line 2565 and defined

Answer (score 0):

I think it has to be

```
function getQuery($id){
$sql = "SELECT firstname FROM players WHERE id = $id";

$stmt = $this->em->getConnection()->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute();
$players = $stmt->fetchAll();
```

"$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();" is not needed anymore because you already injected the Doctrine Entity Manager in your construct as $this->em.